# Using SPUtility script with If Statement

Tags: javascript, sputility

I am currently using a PreSaveAction script to check a field to make sure it is filled out before saving the form.

However, while testing different situations, I realized that if "Reviewer 1" rejects the approval in the first step, then "Reviewer 2" would not be required because the workflow would end.

I wrote this script using the SPutility script to change the status of the Reviewer 2 field if Reviewer 1 selects "reject".

I'm not very good at syntax and writing JS, so could someone take a look at it please?

```
<script>
// wait for the window to load
$(document).ready(function () {
   var app-rej1= "Approve/Reject-1"
   if(app-rej1){=== "Rejected"}
   // Change status of 'Reviewer 2' field if 'Approve/Reject-1' equals rejected.
      SPUtility.GetSPField('Reviewer 2').SetValue('John Smith');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var app-rej1 = "Approve/Reject-1";
    if(app-rej1 === "Rejected") {
    // Change status of 'Reviewer 2' field if 'Approve/Reject-1' equals rejected.
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Reviewer 2').SetValue('John Smith');
    }
});
```

The trouble is, it looks like on document load you're creating and setting a variable (app-rej1) every time the page loads. So it'll only ever be that value of "Approve/Reject-1" at the time the if statement is read.

You may need something more like this, although I'm just taking a stab at it, because I don't have any clue as to the nature of the rest of your code...

```
var app-rej1;

// do stuff to determine the value of app-rej1

$(document).ready(function () {
    if(app-rej1 === "Rejected") {
    // Change status of 'Reviewer 2' field if 'Approve/Reject-1' equals rejected.
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Reviewer 2').SetValue('John Smith');
    }
});
```